# Best way to create a Day model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create an object called Day and in that I want to store other object instances called Meeting.

My question is:
What is the best way to create the object Day with datetime reference. Is there a built in model structure or something that lets me use days as objects or should I simply create the model called Day and give it a variable that is datetime?

Thanks in advance from a noobie <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure your database like this:

```
class DayModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class MeetingModel(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(DayModel, related_name="meetings")
    time = models.TimeField()
```

Comment: I would suggest to add `related_name` to `day` field in `MeetingModel` so that OP can reference it from `DayModel`.